# How to make Microsoft Teams home site app work across different tenants

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I have created a home site app for Microsoft Teams that renders a SharePoint communication site ([sharepoint](https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MyCommSite)) in a personal tab by following the article Teams App with SharePoint. When I install the app in Teams desktop within the same tenant, it is working fine.

When installing the app in another tenant ([fabrikam.sharepoint](https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com)), where the user is added as a guest to the tenant having the SharePoint site ([contoso.sharepoint](https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MyCommSite)), the site content does not load in Teams desktop. When accessing in a browser tab, the app starts working once I manually open the SharePoint site in a new tab.

The manifest I'm using for the app:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.8",
  "id": "80322562-deed-42fa-88e7-373884e370f2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageName": "MyTeamsApp",
  "developer": {
    "name": "microsoft.com",
    "websiteUrl": "https://MyTeamsApp",
    "privacyUrl": "https://MyTeamsApp/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://MyTeamsApp/tou.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "MyTeamsApp Home Site",
    "full": "MyTeamsApp Home Site App for Teams"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "This is Tone Training Home Site app for Teams",
    "full": "This is the Tone Training Home Site app packaged for Teams"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "TeamsOutline.png",
    "color": "TeamsColor.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [],
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "MyTeamsAppHome",
      "name": "My Teams App Home",
      "contentUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/sites/MyTeamsApp",
      "websiteUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MyTeamsApp",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
    "resource": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"
  },
  "bots": [],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "*.login.microsoftonline.com",
    "*.sharepoint.com",
    "*.sharepoint-df.com",
    "spoppe-a.akamaihd.net",
    "spoprod-a.akamaihd.net",
    "resourceseng.blob.core.windows.net",
    "msft.spoppe.com"
  ],
  "isFullScreen": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do in concept is basically the same as the new "Viva Connections" capability from Microsoft, so you should consider going that route instead as it offers what you're doing plus a whole lot more. I just blogged about the background of that, with links to relevant Microsoft content, so have a look at https://hilton.giesenow.com/2021-03-31-understanding-viva-connections-app-package

In terms of the actual problem you're having though, I don't think you'll be able to get this to work on the desktop because of how the Teams app manages the current login context, but perhaps someone else will have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Teams don't support the option to view a SharePoint page/site across tenants. Guest users are not supported yet either.